# Unused Component Import solves error Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'xx' before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this service file, where all other services are stored. Beside importing all services, which are used in the frontend, I store one component in the import section.

```
import { VacationComponent } from 'app/view/vacation/vacation.component';
```

The import is not being used in the service file. When removing the import I get the following error:

```
main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'nX' before initialization
at main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:1825981
at Module.zUnb (main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:1826937)
at l (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:552)
at 0 (main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:5659)
at l (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:552)
at t (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:421)
at Array.r [as push] (runtime-es2015.66c79b9d36e7169e27b0.js:1:293)
at main-es2015.0cad4195744251a340b5.js:1:47
```

. I don't understand how an unused import can fix this error. Also the imported component has no variable "nX" in it. The main file referenced from the error contains a definition of nX which looks like the following:

```
let nX=(()=>{class t{constructor(t,e){this.service=t,this.dialog=e,this.isChecked=!1}
```

I see no connection to the imported Component file.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of files in your error message, and it's not obvious which one is which.

> The main file referenced from the error contains a definition of nX

But is it defined before being used?

Importing an unused component would help resolve this `nX` variable problem by defining that variable in global scope by itself.

For exmaple, if that unused import does `window.nX = "bla";`, the variable will no longer be undefined.

It would be helpful if you paste the content of the file where the error occurred - and line where it occurred.
Based on given info, my assumption is that you try to use `nX` *before* you define it in that file.

Comment: the file in which nx is defined is from a prod build and therefore contains a lot of lines. The component which is imported has no reference to nX.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed now.
The problematic component wasn't the VacationComponent which was imported, but the component which was referenced in the Main file.
I am not sure why importing the VacationComponent fixed it at first, but it seems to work now without it since the underlaying problem in the other component is fixed.